# how to find non trivial subgroups of a group

Tags: group-theory, number-theory, elementary-number-theory

I am currently working on number theory and I have come across a question asking for non-trivial subgroups of a given group. the question states that G = Z*73, I know this is equal to all values of 73 which are inversable so that is 1..72.

I understand that a subgroup must satisfy closure, identity, inverses and be associative.

i know that trivial subgroups are the ones that any group can have, when the subset is equal to the identity element or G itself.

but when trying to work out non-trivial ones, as it is a large number 73, I don't know how I would go about working out subgroups of it?

any infomration would be appreciated!

Comment: You do know Lagrange's theorem?

Comment: Just for getting an idea, pick any number and see what subgroup it generates. If $73$ is too large, why not try $\Bbb Z_7^\times$ instead. For example, the group generated by $6$ contains only $6$ and $1$, because $6\cdot6=36=1$.

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown all I know about Lagrange's theorem is that If subset H ≤ G then |H| divides |G|

Comment: To test if some proper non-trivial subset is a subgroup, you don't need to test associativity, you get that for free from the over-group and it can be a pain in the neck to test. Whether the others hold should be a lot easier to check.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By Lagrange, every subgroup of $U(73)$ has order $d\mid \phi(73)=72$ Consider the subgroup $U=\langle 2\rangle $, generated by $2$. Since $2^9\equiv 1\bmod 73$, $U$ is a non-trivial subgroup of $U(73)$, having order $d=9$.

Answer (score 0):

*Hint:* Take any element of $g \in G$ with $g\ne 1$, and consider the subgroup generated by $g^2$. This subgroup will not be the whole group when the order of $G$ is even.

For instance, the subgroup generated by $4=2^2$ is not the whole group. Indeed, it has order $9$. But the point is that you don't need to compute its order.

Comment: OP is in the group of units.

Comment: @Randall. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

As you've stated, $|\mathbb{Z}_{73}^*| = 72$. In short, for every possible factor $n$ of $72$ there exists a subgroup of order $n$ (generated in turn by an element of order $n$). This is specifically for this group, though it also holds for other groups $\mathbb{Z}_p^*$ where $p$ is prime.

Following on  Jesko's comment, maybe something smaller like $\mathbb{Z}_{13}^*$ would help illuminate. This has order $12$ and elements as follows:
$$
\mathbb{Z}_{13}^* = \{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12\}
$$
Let's try taking the powers of 2 mod 13. In order, they are:
$$
2, 4, 8, 3, 6, 12, 11, 9, 5, 10, 7, 1, 2, \dots
$$
Therefore, the element $2$ generates the entire group $\mathbb{Z}_{13}^*$. This is a trivial subgroup so let's try the powers of 3 mod 13:
$$
3, 9, 1, 3, 9, 1, \dots
$$
This generates the subgroup $\{1, 3, 9\}$, which you can now check the group axioms on if you like. You should also find that there are subgroups of order 2, 4, 6 (all the factors of 12).

A very analogous thing happens with $\mathbb{Z}_{73}^*$. I'd recommend you start with the powers of 2 to get a feel for it. If I'm not mistaken there should be 12 distinct subgroups.

Comment: The first paragraph is somewhat nontrivial, and is fairly specific to this case.

Comment: @Tobias Yes, thank you, you're quite right. I've been working with $\mathbb{Z}_p^*$ so much with A-level students recently that I've started slipping and saying all groups satisfy these conditions...

Answer (score 0):

Right in addition to Lagrange's Theorem (which does not guarantee existence) you could also apply Sylow's Theorem. We see that $72 = 2^{3}3^{2}$ so maybe we can find out how many Sylow 2-subgroups we have.

Let $n_{2}$ be the number of Sylow 2-subgroups, now we have some conditions on $n_2$. Those being:

1. $n_2 \mid 9$
2. $n_2 \equiv 1 \mod{2}$

We can see here that $n_2$ can be $3$ or $9$ here. So there is definitely at least $2$ subgroups of order $2$. Well we're in luck because $2$ is prime, meaning that these subgroups are going to be cyclic. Are you able to find an element of your group which has order $2$ and generates a subgroup of order $2$ under the operation?